# ul is not properly formatted by css

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

trying to create a list in an asp.net mvc 4 app with for each item an img, link to shop, address per row
The  has some css style rules but now it is all stuffed:
http://jsfiddle.net/tmmW3/

a fragment of the css :

```
ul#TopShops
{
     list-style-type: none;
}

ul#TopShops small
{
     font-size:10px;
     padding:1px;
}

li {
    position:relative;
    padding:1px;
}
```

razor:

```
   <ul id="TopShops">

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <h3>
                    <a href="@item.url">@item.name</a>
                    <a href="@item.url"><img src="@item.imagename" /></a>
                    <small>@item.address</small>

                </h3>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Comment: do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/tmmW3/5/ ?

Comment: yes heaps better thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `display: table-row;` to your `li`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tmmW3/5)